ODBC connection in Azure Container Instances fails due to outbound public IP's
I am trying to use ODBC in order to make a connection with a SQL database using Azure Container Instances. However, it fails everytime because random public IP addresses are being used for outbound traffic apparently:
Error in dbConnect():
! ODBC failed with error 00000 from [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server].
✖ Cannot open server [servername] requested by the login. Client with IP address '4.175.8.136' is not allowed to access the server.
Is there any way to use private IP for outbound traffic, or use a static public IP address (which can be whitelisted in that case). Or any other service I can use like Container Apps?
Thanks.

If you're using Azure SQL there's an option you can turn on to allow connections from Azure services. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/firewall-configure?view=azuresql#connections-from-inside-azure
Another way if you're using Managed Instance is to go to your app service -> Networking -> VNet Integration and add your app service to a subnet that's in the same VNet as your Managed Instance server.

Error in `dbConnect()`: ! ODBC failed with error 00000 from [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]. ✖ Cannot open server [servername] requested by the login. Client with IP address '4.175.8.136' is not allowed to access the server.

Here is the issue from sql server side. SQL server is not allowing the Ip address that may be the reason to get above error. If you're using Azure SQL to provide access to sql server from Azure resource, you have  Allow azure services and resources to the server  option at sql server networking tab check that option and save it as shown below:

Then you don't need to whitelist the Ip address again and again to Azure SQL database while connecting from azure container instance.
